# Close main application if "helper" application closed

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a wrapper application, which opens an other application, let's call it helper app. This app is inside the wrapper application Resource folder.

I would like to close the main application, after the helper app was closed. How can I achieve this?

I would like to also know, how can I quit the wrapper app, after the helper opened.

Comment: Are you developing for OSX or iOS?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I develop for OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you developing for OSX (10.6 and later ) ?
In this case use [NSRunningApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to terminate the wrapper application.

```
@implementation AppDelegate // Helper Application delegate
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSArray *apps = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.yourApplication.Launcher"];
    if ([apps count])
        [(NSRunningApplication *)[apps objectAtIndex:0] terminate];
}
@end
```

And you can launch your Helper synchronously with [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :

```
- (void)launchHelper // Wrapper launch method
{
    NSURL *helperURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Helper" withExtension:@"app"];
    if (helperURL)
    {
        NSError *err = nil;

        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplicationAtURL:helprURL options:NSWorkspaceLaunchAllowingClassicStartup configuration:nil error:&err];
        // here Helper 'main' have been called
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

short answer - you can't!

Every application work in sandbox mode. You can call other application but you lose control on your (of course you can use AppDelegate standard method to handle enter/back foreground/bacground actions but that's it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I go then with the post which I marked accepted, which quits the wrapper app after it started the helper app.